# MacBook Air unable to write to external Harddisk

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-disk

I have a MacBook Air with mac OS Version 10.13.4 and I am not able to write to external disks formatted in format "Windows NT File System (NTFS)".

It is definitely not an issue with the drive as I am able to write to the drive on Windows and Linux systems following these guidelines:

1. Plug the drive into a free USB slot.

What are the corresponding instructions for a Mac? I am able to *read* from the external drive, but not to *write*. What are the precise, clear and direct instructions to be able to write to an external disk? (Disk, not sick)...

Answer (score 3):

MacOS does not natively write to NTFS. Although it has write drivers installed, which can be activated via the command line following [this set of instructions](http://osxdaily.com/2013/10/02/enable-ntfs-write-support-mac-os-x/), this is complicated. Most users install a third-party driver such as [OSX Fuse](https://osxfuse.github.io) or [Tuxera](https://www.tuxera.com/products/tuxera-ntfs-for-mac/) to write to NTFS. The only file systems that natively support read and write on MacOS, Windows, and Linux are ExFAT and FAT32.

Comment: That is partially incorrect. Apple includes drivers but you must turn them on. Please add this to your answer.

Comment: @Josh my understanding was that Apple includes READ drivers, but not WRITE drivers. The read drivers are on automatically, but you need to use a third party driver like mentioned above to write. Is this incorrect, and if so, where can I find more information about it?

Comment: http://osxdaily.com/2013/10/02/enable-ntfs-write-support-mac-os-x/

Comment: OSX Fuse does not seem to work. I installed it, restarted the mac, but still cannot write on the external disk

Comment: The help in the link also does not help - I do not get a UUID (with DRIVENAME replaced accordingly...). The diskutil does not list a UUID...

Comment: MacOS includes write support for NTFS, but that support is turned off for a reason.  You enable it at your own risk.

Answer (score 3):

MacOS does not allow the user to write to `NTFS` formatted disks. You could use `ExFAT`, which is the one I am using (It is supported in any desktop platform).

Comment: Is such a format also supported by TV sets? I mean, can I connect a disk formatted in such a way to a TV to watch a movie?

Comment: Almost all the TVs support NTFS or/and FAT32 but not ExFat. You could use FAT32 if you need the fullest compatibility with any device. However, you could not add more than 4GB single file to FAT32 formatted disks.

Comment: I would have to format the whole disk and rewrite the whole content. 

I will stick to the following solution: 1. Put files on a USB stick. 2. Use a computer that works (i.e. anything without an apple logo on it). 3. Copy the files to the hard drive.